# Paredit: remove unwanted keybindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, paredit

I'm trying ParEdit mode and this is something that it does not the way I'd want: it shadows the original binding for <kbd>C-M-F</kbd> and replaces it with <kbd>C-M-f</kbd>. I.e. it forwards sexp instead of selecting it :| I couldn't find the place where the bindings are defined at the first glance.

Any way to cancel this behaviour? Or what would be the analogue command in ParEdit for selecting an sexp?

**EDIT:**

To give you a better idea of what happens, if I do <kbd>C-h k</kbd> while ParEdit is active, and then <kbd>C-M-S-f</kbd> this is what I get:

```
C-M-f (translated from C-M-S-f) runs the command paredit-forward,
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `paredit.el'.

It is bound to C-M-f.

(paredit-forward)

Move forward an S-expression, or up an S-expression forward.
If there are no more S-expressions in this one before the closing
  delimiter, move past that closing delimiter; otherwise, move forward
  past the S-expression following the point.

C-M-f

(foo |(bar baz) quux)
  ->
(foo (bar baz)| quux)

(foo (bar)|)
  ->
(foo (bar))|

[back]
```

I don't want it to translate anything, this is absolutely undesired behaviour.

Comment: "C-h b" will show all keybindinds, hence you will be able to search for the selection command. Did you try to edit paredit.el and alter/remove the C-M f keybiding? In my version is in line 394

Comment: Can't see any binding of `C-M-F` in paredit. While `C-M-f` seeks to deliver a smarter `forward-sexp`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(eval-after-load "paredit"
  '(progn
    (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-M-f") nil)))
```

Strictly speaking the progn is unnecessary, but you might want to redefine/remove more keys afterwards

**EDIT**

Unlike forward-sexp, paredit-forward doesn't check whether shift is pressed. You could try using this

```
(eval-after-load "paredit"
  '(progn
    (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-M-S-f") 
     (lambda ()
       (interactive)
       (unless (region-active-p)
         (set-mark (point)))
       (paredit-forward)))))
```

**EDIT**

An alternative way to do the same thing (select the following sexp), would be C-M-space. Then, should you want to do so, you can swap point and mark with C-x C-x (or C-x (no delay here) C-x C-x if you use CUA)

**EDIT (last?)**

The proper way to make a function also mark when shift is pressed is this:

```
(put 'paredit-forward 'CUA 'move)
```

Comment: What Paredit version are you using?  Because here, with Paredit 23 (the last stable version), setting the `'CUA` property to `'move` does not work.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm using `24 (beta)` right now, which handles Shift itself. FWIW, I'm on Emacs `24.4.1`.

Comment: Then that is the difference: the Changelog for Paredit 24 (beta) states "Motion commands support shift selection in GNU Emacs 24 and later."

Comment: Do you think that Paredit 24 (beta) is stable enough for general use?

Comment: I haven't had any problems with it

Answer (score 2):

Paredit isn't translating the keys.  Emacs is.  It's the same in every mode.  If there's no binding for C-M-F, Emacs will try C-M-f instead.

If you want to select the S-expression after the point, the standard Emacs key for this is C-M-SPC.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting a very old question, but I think I know a more general solution to this.

`paredit` is a very old package that predates modern packaging hygiene. i.e. aggressive setting of default keybindings.

To undo that, run this after loading the paredit package:

```
  (paredit-do-commands (spec keys _fn _examples) nil
    (dolist (key keys)
      (define-key paredit-mode-map (read-kbd-macro key) nil)))
```

now you're back to no keybindings, and you can use the regular mechanisms. Read the value (not the documentation) on `paredit-commands` to see which commands are available and what their default bindings are, some of which you might want to retain.